# Mark a cart as complete from a plugin

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

How do I mark a cart as complete from a plugin?
I tried setting isComplete = 1, it gets moved to orders but it is still a cart.

Answer (score 2):

When you take a look at the `BookingsController` you can see exactly what happens when you need to mark an order as complete

```PHP
public function actionCompleteOrder(): Response
{
    $this->requireAcceptsJson();
    $orderId = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getParam('orderId');

    $order = Plugin::getInstance()->getOrders()->getOrderById($orderId);

    if ($order && !$order->isCompleted && $order->markAsComplete()) {
        $date = new \DateTime($order->dateOrdered);
        return $this->asJson(['success' => true, 'dateOrdered' => $date]);
    }

    return $this->asErrorJson(Craft::t('commerce', 'Could not mark the order as completed.'));
}
```

So all you need to do is

```php
$order->markAsComplete();
```

Which does

```PHP
$this->isCompleted = true;
$this->dateOrdered = Db::prepareDateForDb(new \DateTime());
$this->reference = 'xxxx';
$this->orderStatusId = y;
```

You need to set the 4 parameters above to complete an order correctly, not just the `isComplete`